# Data was reset from the postgresql table after deleting the Packages file

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, database, postgresql

I created my project in python using postgresql on windows in a wsl environment. And accidentally deleted the file at the address Appdata/Local/Packages. After that, everything broke down and the project stopped opening. But it doesn't bother me much, I can restore it. But when I went into the table I was working with using pgadmin, I found that the data table I was working with in the project had lost most of the data. It still exists. But the data in it does not contain the latest information that I entered there, but the old one, when it was still small and I was just starting to work. I don't understand what happened. I would understand if the table was completely deleted, but it is present, it is just not in its latest version. What could this be related to? Is there any way I can fix this and get my data back?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.